# How can I fix a hole near an outside corner of my plaster wall?

Tags: repair, walls, hole-repair

I have this hole in my kitchen. The whole paint layer is gone and you can see the metal support beneath it.

[image]

Here's a picture also showing the "culprit":

[image]

I've never fixed a wall before, I'm a complete beginner in home repair.

How can I go about fixing this? Is this something that can be fixed with some spackle? Or is the hole too large for that?

I have a similar problem, though smaller, in the living room:

[image]

What approach can I use for fixing this one?

Comment: FYI, what you see there is metal "corner bead". It provides the straight line to which plaster is applied, as well as support. It ends where you see the edge on the left in that hole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get some gypsum plaster from your home store. For the first picture, make sure the rest of the plaster there is sound, no cracks. If there are cracks, remove that portion. Then knock out the plaster in the holes in the metal support. You'll need that area cleared so the new plaster can sink in and grab hold. Then mix some plaster according to the package instruction and spread it in the hole with a trowel or drywall taping blade larger than the hole so you get a smooth surface. After letting it dry, sand and touch up if needed.

You can use some of the same plaster to fix the area shown in the second picture. Put some plaster on your trowel or blade and work from the corner to each side. When dry sand and touch up with more plaster if needed.

Add a stop to the door to prevent smashing the wall again.

Comment: The corner looks to be metal I would not suggest trying to remove that but just filling.

Comment: @ Yes, just fill in.

Comment: You might find that the fixed and sanded patch is smoother than the surrounding wall and will show even when painted.  If that bothers you, there are 'orange peel' mud texture sprays that can help.

Comment: In the first picture, I think JACK is indicating that the plaster _in the holes_ in the metal should be knocked out so the new plaster can squeeze in and form a key to hold the new stuff in place. I don't think he's suggesting attempting to remove the metal corner bead.

Comment: @FreeMan  Right you are.